# Apache Dynamic Virtual Hosts - 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, macos, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am trying to configure the Apache server on my MacBooks (running Lion OS) to handle dynamic virtual hosts. I have managed to get it "working" but I whenever I access the domain I get a 403 Forbidden message. The hosts file is configured to point to 127.0.0.1 whenever one of these domains are requested. The httpd.conf is shown below:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/web"

<Directory "/web">    
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ScriptAlias /web/cgi-bin/
</Directory>

UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /web/%2/%1/public_html
```

This is set up so that http://foo.bar/ goes to "/web/bar/foo/public_html/".

I have checked the permissions on all the directories and files and they are all set to '777'. I have Googled for hours and hours and I am still getting 403 Forbidden. If there is anyone that can help me that would be greatly appreciated.

-Sam

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Also, all my files are owned by _www, so I don't know why there are permission problems. Also my parent folders are accessible to _www.

Comment: check: http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2004/08/05/virtual_host/ far at the end. helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it right, it's about permission. Check your site's parent folder permission, it might be stuck somehow on one of it's parent folder, make sure all of you site's parent folder from the root are readable by apache.